# How to specify assumptions without typing out functions

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, assumptions, keyboard

So I want to add assumptions in carrying out integration. I know I could use the Integrate function:

```
Integrate[V Exp[-x/a] ,{x,0,10}, Assumptions->a>0]
```

but this gets very tedious when I could just use the shortcut

esc + dintt + esc

in the case of a definite integral. Is there any way to specify assumptions using shortcut functions like this, or does one HAVE to use the Integrate function?

Thanks!

Comment: Check the docs for the Notation package: Notation/tutorial/NotationSymbolizeAndInfixNotation

Answer (score 2):

The `AddInputAlias` function in the `Notation` package solves this problem. To use the example input alias created below, simply type Esc apply Esc.

```
<< Notation`;
AddInputAlias[ParsedBoxWrapper[
    RowBox[{"\[Placeholder]", " ", OverscriptBox["\[LongRightArrow]", 
    RowBox[{" ", "Apply", " "}]], " ", "\[Placeholder]", " "}]], "apply"]
```